# Updating a column with the same value towards b-tree index

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have these 2 indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx1" ON "posts"("category", "feed", "create_time" DESC);

CREATE INDEX "idx2" ON "posts"("feed", "create_time" DESC);
```

I executed this update  function:

```
UPDATE "posts"
SET "attribute" = 'something' AND "feed" = function("attribute")
WHERE "id" = '123';
```

The `function("attribute")` calculates the **feed** based on **attribute** column, and most of the time **feed** doesn't change. Does this mean indexes **idx1** and **idx2** wouldn't restructure when the feed is updated to the same value, hence making the update quite fast?

Even though I don't have any update issues or slow latency, this might be wise to think ahead.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "restructure", but the index needs to be updated to point at the new row instead of the old row in any case.

Answer (score 0):

If the update is degenerate, then it could qualify for a Heap-Only-Tuple update, in which case the indexes would not need to be maintained. But for that to apply, there needs to be enough free space in that same page to hold a new copy of the tuple.

Comment: But I also need to update the "attribute", and if I put the "AND NOT" statement, the update statement won't be triggered

Comment: Ah, OK, then you can't do that, I've removed that part.  But the HOT update thing still applies, since "attribute" appears not to be indexed.

Comment: thank you, I have researched this and looks like adjusting the "fillfactor" would be the best possible solution for now :)